# What is the difference between camera model focal length and optics focal length

Tags: opencv, camera

From [Edmond Optics website](http://www.edmundoptics.com/resources/application-notes/imaging/understanding-focal-length-and-field-of-view/),

it shows a simplified way to calculate "focal length", given the censor size and the field of view.

From [OpenCV camera calibration](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html),

OpenCV has the function to calculate "focal length for x and y" in camera model.

Are they two different focal length definitions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not an expert, but as far as I know focal length is independent of x and y.
Field of view can be calculated if you know the focal length and the sensor size with:

```
FOV = arctan(D/2F)
```

Where `D` is the sensor size and `F` is the focal length.

First we need to understand that in most cases you will have different values for HorizontalFOV and VerticalFOV.
The sensor size have x and y dimensions that can be different, but in most cases the manufacturer of the camera provides only the diagonal size and not the horizontal and vertical sizes.
So from the formula above, if you know the x,y FOV and you have only the diagonal sensor size, you might actually get different focal length for x,y even though physically it is not like that.